# Setting relative path in jar to be included in Eclipse for project running on Tomcat Server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am working on Eclipse Java.

I am editing an open source jar source code, and then I have to export it as jar to be included in another project. I want that jar code should load some files from a directory relative to the project where the jar is included as a library.

The problem is that the project in which I need to place the jar is run on Tomcat Server, so has no absolute path. i.e. its path is displayed:

```
/MyProjectName
```

And I have tried in jar source code.

`System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get relative path but it gives me path to eclipse.exe. So I am not able to set relative directory path.

Comment: Have you put your files inside your war and tried to load them? Because in a web application, that is the only place that you can load files with respect to that war's context. Rest other files can only be loaded as absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your resource directory is in the classpath such as within the JAR file or in Tomcat's lib directory. Then use `Class.getResource()` to locate it.

For example:

```
mylib.jar:
  |- com
  |  |- me
  |      |- My.class
  `- resources
       `- my.file
```

You would the get a URL to `my.file` my doing `Class.getResource("resources/my.file")`